# Error when implementing Global Timeout

Tags: testing, junit

Is there any architectural difference in how test runs in Junit when [timeout is set for test method](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Timeout-for-tests)  and when its not set?

I am getting security errors(Data Security system requires an ApplSession to be created and valid )(related to session) when I implement timeout,even when the test is not timing out.
What is the way to solve the issue?
This isn't the complete stack trace but this is what I can share:

```
         sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
         sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
         java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
         org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
         org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
         org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
         org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
         org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
         org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
 org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$StatementThread.run(FailOnTimeout.java:62)
```

Comment: Can you give some more details about "getting security errors(related to session)".

Comment: Hi I am not allowed to share that.I think this is because when the test runs in a new thread,it goies out of the context.So when its trying to access view objects this error is thrown "Data Security system requires an ApplSession to be created and valid "

Comment: Actually the error is because the session doesnot exist.session is null when @timeout is applied.Otherwise its running fine

Answer (score 0):

Yes, JUnit runs tests with a timeout annotation differently. I also experienced that.

As far as I know, JUnit executes each test case with a timeout in a separated thread to be able to stop / kill it when the timeout occurs.
Consequently, the code in the **test case** may have a different context than expected or **may be outside the session context**.

**How to solve the problem:**

- Create a static method, annotate it with `@BeforeClass`, retrieve the current session and store it to a static field (this must be done outside the test case)
- Create a runnable with the (server) session of the static field as context, implement the test logic in the runnable and execute it
- Make sure that the assertion exceptions which are thrown inside the runnable are re-thrown to the test case method

The code could look like this (depending on your framework):

```
private static ISession s_session;

@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() throws ProcessingException {
  s_session = AbstractServerSession.get();
}

@Test(timeout = 5000)
public void testX() throws Throwable {
  JobForServerTestcaseWithTimeout job = new JobForServerTestcaseWithTimeout(s_session) {
    @Override
    protected void executeTest() throws Exception {
      //put the test logic here
      assertTrue(true);
    }
  };

  job.runAndCheckAssertions();
}
```

The class `JobForServerTestcaseWithTimeout` is a thread with a server session which runs the `executeTest()` method in a try-catch-block. It catches the first exception (failing assertions cause an `AssertionError`) and stores it to a member variable. `runAndCheckAssertions()` checks whether an exception had occurred and if so it will rethrow it.

The actual test logic is located in the implementation of `executeTest()`. However, `executeTest()` could just invoke a method `testXInternal()` (which could be implemented directly the test class) to make the code more readable.

Comment: This will require to change each and every test case which I have written,which is huge.Is there any other workaround?

Comment: Probably, another way exists to attach the context to the current thread. This depends on your framework.